# How to create a hover effect on a CTA button in a newsletter?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a newsletter in Salesforce Pardot and I want the CTA buttons to change color when you hover over them.

I have 2 different CTA buttons.

For the transparent CTA buttons I'm using this CSS and that's working:

```
.tr1:hover { background: #F7F36D !important; }
.tr1:hover td { background: transparent; }

.tr2:hover { background: #6BCDDD !important; }
.tr2:hover td { background: transparent; }
```

Etcetera

But I also have a black CTA button where I want to change the bg color (to #E0A9D5) as well as the font color (to #000000). But somehow I can't seem to get it working :(

This is the HTML code:

```
<tr class="tr6">
   <td align="center" class="em_white" height="36" style="height: 36px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0px 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border-style:solid; border-radius: 0px; border-width: 2px; border-color: black;" valign="middle"><a href="#" pardot-region="editable-link" pardot-region-type="link" style="color:#E0A9D5" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum dolor »</a></td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone help me with the CSS part? Thanks!

Comment: Your html code has been stripped out. Be sure to add it using the formatting options in the editor.

Comment: _"But somehow I can't seem to get it working :("_ - then show us what you tried at least.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `hover` property, you can simply use `:hover` on any selector. Here is a quick example.

```css
button:hover {
background:yellow;
transform:scale(200%);
}
```

```html
<button>A button</button>
```

Now if you want to make *another* element change when you hover on one element, you can use a code like this:

```css
div:hover ~ span {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1">a div here</div>
<span>span</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't know how to use this code. Can't i use this CSS script but then with some small adjustments? And I also want to change the font color>>         .tr6:hover { background: #F7F36D !important; }
.tr1:hover td { background: transparent; }

Comment: Yes, a ;problem here is that your are inlining style to your `.tr6` class *inside the HTML element*; when you then want to modify it using regular *inlined CSS* (in a `style` div or an external stylesheet), the *inlined CSS within your HTML element code has priority*. So it does not work. You need to put all your CSS code in a stylesheet or inline it in your HTML code inside a `style` div. Don't inline anything inside the HTML element code. I will update my answer to try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great practice to have lots of inline style added to your html elements. Therefore, you should strip out the content s of the style="...".

Then instead, choose an appropriate selector, eg the class="em_white" and add style there instead:

```
.em_white {... Add stripped out style here...}
```

After that, you can then target the anchor within the tr tag, with something like:

```
.em_white a {background-color:#f00; color:#000}
.em_white a:hover {background-color:#000; color:#fff}
```

The added benefit to this is that there is a lot less duplication and also your code will become easier to read. You also only need to make one change to the CSS to effect all elements with that class.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I'm now using this in css:  .em_white1 a {background-color:#000; color:#E0A9D5; text-decoration: none}
.em_white1 a:hover {background-color:#E0A9D5; color:#000; text-decoration: none}. The background is changing but not the whole CTA button. And the font-color doesn't change to black when I hover over it.  I don't understand why this works for the transparant button but isnt working for the black button

Comment: That is because each parent element will have default padding and margin. An element will take the background colour of a parent if it is not explicitly defined for itself. Often it's fine to just define a high level parent elements background colour then, there is no need to define child elements as they inherit the parent color.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by styling both `tr6` as `em_white`. I know this is not the right way to do it, but at least it's working.

```
.tr6 td { background: #000000; }
.tr6:hover td { background: #E0A9D5; }

.em_white1 a { text-decoration: none; color: #E0A9D5; }
.em_white1:hover a { text-decoration: none; color: #000000; }
```

Comment: you didn't need to go quite that far to the tr6. You can probably achieve the same effect with 
.em_white1 { background: #000000; }
.em_white1:hover { background: #E0A9D5; }
Glad you got it working!